# Dimension of the subspace of a vector space spanned by the following vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I know that in order to find a subsequence that is a basis of a subspace is to check whether the given vectors are linearly independent and whether they span the subspace.

However how can I find the dimensions of the subspaces of a vector space K^n ?

[image]

Comment: A straightforward approach is to use the [gram schmidt method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) and count all non-zero vectors in the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Write the coordinates of the vectors as row vectors of a matrix, and perform row reduction of this matrix. The rank of the matrix  will be the dimension of the subspace, and the non-zero lines in the final matrix will correspond to the vectors that span the subspace.

Comment: We can even put them in columns and do the same process and at the end of rref the pivot columns of the rref will correspond to the basis. Note: not the columns in RREF will become basis. Isnt this also correct.